# how to make a div grow to cover a paragraph in javascript with transition?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to make a transition with a div that should grow and overlap a text. 
Here are my codes

```js
  const box = document.querySelector("#box");
  const mybutt = document.querySelector("#mybutt");

  mybutt.addEventListener("click", transitionfunction);

 function transitionfunction() {
  if(box.style.height != "100px"){
    box.style.height = "100px";
    box.style.transition = "2s";
    }
  else {
   box.style.height = "50px";
   box.style.transition = "2s";
    }
  }
```

```css
#box {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
 }

 #para {
  postion: fixed;
 }
```

```html
  <div id="parentdiv">
   <div id="box"></div>
   <p id="para">Help</p>
 </div>
 <button id="mybutt">click</button>
```

At the moment, on the click of the button, both the button and the paragraph `para` move down, I want them to be fixed and I want the div, `#box` to cover the `para` but its not working. I tried putting it to fixed but doesnt work. And on the click on the button again, it should reveal the text again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `position: fixed;`, you should manually set the `top` property.

To make a `div` overlay some text, use `z-index`

```js
const box = document.querySelector("#box");
const mybutt = document.querySelector("#mybutt");

mybutt.addEventListener("click", transitionfunction);

function transitionfunction() {
    if (box.style.height != "100px"){
        box.style.height = "100px";
        box.style.transition = "2s";
    } else {
       box.style.height = "50px";
       box.style.transition = "2s";
    }
}
```

```css
#mybutt {
    position: fixed;
    top: 120px;
}

#box {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#para {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentdiv">
   <div id="box"></div>
   <p id="para">Help</p>
</div>
<button id="mybutt">click</button>
```

Comment: thank you, i need to run a function, lets say `function alerter` which would alert "hello" when the box height is 75 pixel. how would i best accomplish this?

Comment: @craftdeer I think you could use [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) which has a `step` callback executed on each step of the animation. You could check the height inside of it and alert the message.

Comment: Or, if you want to alert the message just in the middle of the transition, you could simply use a `setTimeout` function. If the transition takes 2 seconds, call `setTimeout(() => alert("Hi!"), 1000)`

Comment: Thanks, I donot want to use jQuery and can only work with plain javascript. And I cannot use setTimeout because I want to fetch some data from an api instead of just alerting and I might not have the data in 1 second.

Comment: Anyway, while you are fetching your data transition may finish

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you spelled "position" wrong for `#para`. Change it to:

```
#para {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
}
```

This will keep the paragraph positioned in one spot; it won't move.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed will work, although you might want to use 'absolute' instead if you want it to anchored to it's parent instead of the window itself.

Also, 'position' is misspelled; not sure if it is in your testing code.

The 'top' property has to be set for the element to know *where* to anchor itself, the 'position' property is *what* to anchor to.

HTML

```
<div id="parentdiv">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <p id="para">Help</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="mybutt">click</button>
```

CSS

```
<style>
  #box {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }

  #para {
    position: absolute;
    top:70;
  }
 </style>
```

*You also might want to move '#para' outside '#parentdiv', but it depends what you'll trying to ultimately do, it does work inside too.

**Added:**

To include an alert at 75px, you have to use a function that gives you more granular control(as far as I know at least). This is one solution:

```
 <script>
   const box = document.querySelector("#box");
   const mybutt = document.querySelector("#mybutt");

   mybutt.addEventListener("click", transitionfunction);



  var intHeight = $("#box").css("height").split("p")[0];

  function transitionfunction() {
   if(intHeight < 100) {
        intHeight++;
        $("#box").css("height", intHeight + "px");
        if (intHeight===76)
            alert("75px!")
        requestAnimationFrame(transitionfunction);
     }
     intHeight = $("#box").css("height").split("p")[0];
     mybutt.addEventListener("click", revtransitionfunction);
     mybutt.removeEventListener("click", transitionfunction);

  }

  function revtransitionfunction() {
    if(intHeight >= 50) {
        intHeight--;
        $("#box").css("height", intHeight + "px");
        if (intHeight===74)
            alert("75px!")
        requestAnimationFrame(revtransitionfunction);
    }
    intHeight = $("#box").css("height").split("p")[0];
    mybutt.addEventListener("click", transitionfunction);
    mybutt.removeEventListener("click", revtransitionfunction);


  }
```

Comment: thank you, i need to run a function, lets say `function alerter` which would alert "hello" when the box height is 75 pixel. how would i best accomplish this?

Comment: edited the solution. I used jQuery's css property because it makes the solution simpler and .split (not jQuery), which just lets you get a numerical value that can be manipulated mathematically.